# Передача статического одномерного массива определённого размера в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы

Я хочу передать в функцию статический массив определённого размера, который будет проверяться при компиляции.

```
#include <iostream>
void print(int arr[3])
{
    std::cout << sizeof(arr) << '\n'; //выводит 4 при каждом вызове
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' '; 
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int staticArr2[2] = {8, 5};
    int staticArr3[3] = {2, 4, 7};

    std::cout << sizeof(staticArr2) << '\n'; //выводит 8
    std::cout << sizeof(staticArr3) << '\n'; //выводит 12

    print(staticArr2); // выводит 3 элемент, указывающий на память вне массива
                       // хочется чтобы не компилировалось
    print(staticArr3); // ок
    return 0;
}
```

Но вот конструкция `int arr[3]` воспринимается как `int *` в объявлении входных параметров функции. Подскажите, как можно реализовать передачу массива конкретного размера.

Comment: Прекрасный вопрос, кстати!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться шаблонами для того, чтобы передавать массив как массив, а не как указатель. При таком вызове сохраняется информация о размере массива. Если дополнить код вызовом `static_assert`, то ошибка будет выдаваться во время компиляции.

```
template<size_t N>
void print(int (&arr)[N])
{
    static_assert(N == 3, "Array must contain 3 elements"); // Проверка выполняется
                                                            // во время компиляции
    std::cout << N << ' ' << sizeof(arr) << '\n'; // Размер вычисляется корректно
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' '; 
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

При попытке передать массив из двух элементов будет выведена ошибка:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'void print(int (&)[N]) [with unsigned int N = 2u]':
prog.cpp:22:21:   required from here
prog.cpp:6:2: error: static assertion failed: Array must contain 3 elements
  static_assert(N == 3, "Array must contain 3 elements");
  ^
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Такую шаблонную конструкцию можно воспринимать только как с++ магию, или здесь есть какая то логика? Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно найти дополнительную информацию об этом.

Comment: @Rekiro Что считать магией, а что нет — это решает каждый сам для себя. Стандартная библиотка, boost и прочие привычные вещи понапичканы мозговыносящими конструкциями на шаблонах — они становятся из-за этого магией? Ну а вычисление размера массива с помощью такого шаблона есть в VC++ в виде `_countof`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4108313 На вопрос "почему" во всех деталях, к сожалению, ответить не могу. Обычно ответ звучит как "потому что стандарт такой", а я ни разу не специалист по нюансам стандарта.

Comment: @Discord, ну и как этим пользоваться? Сделайте законченый рабочий пример (думаю, Вы сами убедитесь, что кресты это бред).

Comment: @avp Не понял. Что значит "как пользоваться"? Вызовы этой функции есть в вопросе. Про бред вообще не понял... вы же плюсовик? о_О

Comment: Пример с main, который компилируется и печатает значение sizeof. (а я не не "плюсовик", а "сишник").

Comment: @avp Все мейны с сайзофами есть в вопросе, я не счёл нужным их копипастить. / А ваш профиль говорит, что вы больше плюсовик. :) Впрочем, метки на многих вопросах расставляются от балды, множество народа считает, что эти два языка "почти одно и то же", поэтому статистика из профиля может ошибаться.

Answer (score 1):

Конкретный размер передается отдельным параметром.

В функцию надо передавать два параметра:

- ссылку на первый элемент массива (это имя массива без квадратных скобок
- размерность массива.

Comment: По логике программы функция знает массив какой размерности ей передаётся. И поэтому мне необходимо чтобы передавался именно массив, а не указатель

Comment: "Именно массив"  это и есть указатель на ячейки памяти в которых хранятся данные, это можно сказать разновидность указателя.

Comment: Если уж так надо именно определенный один объект передать - можно и в структуру и в вектор и в список массив затолкать и много куда еще, и передавать уже этот объект. Но у вас я так понимаю задача не в этом, а в простой обычной передаче. Так вот просто и обычно - передать указатель/ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

А Вы надеялись увидеть 12?

С т.з. языка аргумент функции, хоть и описывающий массив с указанием размера все равно является указалем.

И ведь на самом же деле в функцию в стеке (или в некоторых архитектурах в одном из регистров) передается указатель, который в 32-bit системах имеет размер 4 байта (которые Вы и видите на печати).

Причем, даже в gcc, который "на самом деле понимает" размеры массивов (точнее низшие размерности многомерных массивов), например, вот такой код --

```
int 
f (int m, int n, int a[m][n]) {
  printf("n = %d a[n] = %ld\n", n, (long)sizeof(a));
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n || !puts(""); j++)
      printf("%d ", a[i][j]); // обратите внимание он (компайлер) в самом деле учитывает количество элементов в строке матрицы!!!

  return 0;
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  static int c[2][5] = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}};

  f(2, 5, c);
}
```

все равно `sizeof(a)` выдает 4.

Answer (score 1):

можно завернуть массив в структуру и передавать экземпляр структуры в качестве аргумента функции:

```
struct Array3 {
   int items[3];
};

void print(struct Array3 arr) {
   // code here
}
```

Comment: Только надо не забывать, что такой массив будет передаваться "по значению" (в стек будет записана его **копия**) и соответственно все изменения будут утеряны (если не возвращать его обратно и не присваивать оригиналу). Однако, действительно, этот метод с небольшой модификацией можно использовать, если передавать в функцию **адрес** структуры.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно разрешать только определенную размерность, имхо, ей и стоит ограничиться. Т.е. не городить шаблонов со ссылками и `static_assert` внутри, а явно сделать функцию, принимающую сущность, максимально близкую сырому массиву, но являющуюся при этом [объектом первого класса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0). Такой сущностью, в частности, является `std::array`.

[Пример](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/onMGtMidt9nEbmSe):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int size = 3;

void f(const std::array<int, size>& a) {
    for(int e : a) {
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, size> a {1,2,3};
    f(a);
    f({4,5,6});
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. До этого ни разу не обращал внимания на std::array. Это решение проще и понятней за счёт того, что видно необходимую размерность массива при вызове функции где-то в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Передавайте вторым аргументом размер массива. Если хотите, чтобы при определенном размере не компилировалось, в функции проверяйте размер и выкидывайте исключение.